# vue+firebase - firebase hosting deployment failure

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-hosting

I am getting this deployment failure while deploying my vue app to firebase hosting:

```
> myApp@0.1.0 build /home/runner/work/myApp/myApp
> vue-cli-service build


-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error6:40:32 PM

This dependency was not found:

* @/config/firebase in ./src/services/db.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/config/firebase
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myApp@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myApp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-07-09T18_40_32_656Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My db.js file, which is inside `src/services/` has the following import command

`import { categoriesCollection, usersCollection} from "@/config/firebase";`

while my `src/config/firebase.js` file has all the firebase configurations.

Locally everything works fine and I am able to run the app with the db.js working correctly and the firebase calls working well too, but deployment to firebase hosting gives me this error. Anyone knows what might be happening ?

EDIT

Adding more details:

Dir structure

[image]

`firebase.json` :

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  }
}
```

`db.js`

```
import { usersCollection, firebase} from "@/config/firebase";

export async function saveDraftRecipeSingleField(uid, data){
    try{
        await usersCollection.doc(uid).set(data);
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        throw(error);
    }
}

...
```

`firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/firestore";
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: <value>,
    authDomain: <value>,
    projectId: <value>,
    storageBucket: <value>,
    messagingSenderId: <value>,
    appId: <value>,
    measurementId: <value>
  };


// init firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// firestore
const db = firebase.firestore(app);

// auth 
const auth = firebase.auth();

// collection references
const usersCollection = db.collection('users');

// export utils/refs
export {
  firebase,
  auth,
  usersCollection
}
```

I actually have a functions folder which contains all my firebase cloud functions. It is not supposed to be there as part of the app, but needs to live outside the project. Thought i'll move it later. Would that be causing something ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your directory structure and also firebase.json?

Comment: Please add to your question the `db.js` and `firebase.js` files.

Comment: @Dharmaraj and renaud-tarnec , added the details you asked for.

Comment: Just to check, can you try `import { usersCollection, firebase} from "../config/firebase";` 
 instead of `@/config`?

Comment: Just tried, failed with this error - ``` ERROR  Build failed with errors.
This relative module was not found:

* ../config/firebase in ./src/services/db.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1```